# Action of the "Go" button of the ios keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uikeyboard, uitextfielddelegate

How do I bind an action to the **Go** button of the keyboard in iOS ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

### Objective-C

Assuming you're using a UITextField, you could use the `<UITextFieldDelegate>` method `textFieldShouldReturn`.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder]; // Dismiss the keyboard.
    // Execute any additional code

    return YES;
}
```

Don't forget to assign the class you put this code in as the text field's delegate.

```
self.someTextField.delegate = self;
```

Or if you'd prefer to use UIControlEvents, you can do the following

```
[someTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidReturn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];

- (void)textFieldDidReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // Execute additional code
}
```

See [@Wojtek Rutkowski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13066737/716216) to see how to do this in Interface Builder.

### Swift

UITextFieldDelegate

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    let someTextField = UITextField()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        someTextField.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder() // Dismiss the keyboard
        // Execute additional code
        return true
    }
}
```

UIControlEvents

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {
    let someTextField = UITextField()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Action argument can be Selector("textFieldDidReturn:") or "textFieldDidReturn:"
        someTextField.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidReturn:", forControlEvents: .EditingDidEndOnExit)
    }

    func textFieldDidReturn(textField: UITextField!) {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        // Execute additional code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 30):

You can connect `UITextFiled` event `Did End On Exit` in `Connections Inspector`. It is triggered after tapping `Go` / `Return`  / whatever you choose as `Return Key` in `Attributes Inspector`.

[image: Connections Inspector]

Comment: The answer from @0x7fffffff is correct and normally you also have to include some of the delegates so the `UITextField` works correctly. So better stay on the delegates included in code instead working with `UIInterfaceBuilder` too for this little function!