# How to associate iOS keyboard "go" button with UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a search bar in my `SearchViewController`, and currently, when they type into it, there's no **Go** button, it shows only **return**. I want a **Go** button to show in the keyboard, and I want it to be connected to the `- (IBAction)nextButton:(id)sender` that I have connected to the existing **next** `UIButton` under the search bar.

How do I go about enabling this and connecting it in this way? To clarify, the search bar and next button were created in storyboard, not programmatically.

Comment: Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065868/action-of-the-go-button-of-the-ios-keyboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 [textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyGo];
```

or

```
- (void)setReturnKey {
 //use condition here(not empty field)

self.searchField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyGo;
}
```

the other thing as Ghobs said you can find here...

```
 - (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
[textField resignFirstResponder];//Dismiss the keyboard.
//Add action you want to call here.
return YES;
 }
```

source for above code:[Action of the "Go" button of the ios keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065868/action-of-the-go-button-of-the-ios-keyboard)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIReturnKeyType